# Import the entire android repositories to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to create a copy of the entire android repository (which uses the repo tool)
Is there a simple way to duplicate the source into my own GitLab server?

Comment: Does git push not work?

Comment: to push every single project? it seems like a lot of work. There has to be some other, easier way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785592/mass-adding-repos-to-gitlab

Comment: When you say the entire android repo (and all it subprojects), you mean this : https://android.googlesource.com/ ?

Comment: I think you are basically looking at a script that iterates through the repos, clones them, and adds them to your gitlab.

Comment: To complete what @mattm says, make a script that iterates through the repo (parsing the HTML `<table>` should be easy to extract repo URLs). When you have all the URL, you can call GitLab REST API. The API that allows you to create a project can have `import_url` parameter: it will clone the repo at the given URL in the GitLab project you are creating. Take a look [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project)

Answer (score 0):

Even if the android repo uses the [repo tool](https://source.android.com/source/developing.html), you end up with a regular git repo, since a command like `repo sync` is like a `git clone`.

Simply create an empty repo on your GitLab server, then go to your local repo, and:

```
git remote add gitlab /url/of/your/gitlab/repo
git push --mirror gitlab
```

Comment: You are right, But I'm looking for a mass addition of the entire repositories. I don't want to add them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

I want to fix this problem for long time. I think the man who has the same problem is less. because you should be a android system developer not just a simple git user can met this problem.

[There](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md) is a good way to do this.

```
Import bare repositories into your GitLab instance
Notes
The owner of the project will be the first admin
The groups will be created as needed
The owner of the group will be the first admin
Existing projects will be skipped
How to use
Create a new folder inside the git repositories path. This will be the name of the new group.
For omnibus-gitlab, it is located at: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories by default, unless you changed it in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file.
For installations from source, it is usually located at: /home/git/repositories or you can see where your repositories are located by looking at config/gitlab.yml under the gitlab_shell => repos_path entry.
New folder needs to have git user ownership and read/write/execute access for git user and its group:

sudo -u git mkdir /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/new_group
If you are using an installation from source, replace /var/opt/gitlab/git-data with /home/git.

Copy your bare repositories inside this newly created folder:
sudo cp -r /old/git/foo.git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/new_group/

# Do this once when you are done copying git repositories
sudo chown -R git:git /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/new_group/
foo.git needs to be owned by the git user and git users group.

If you are using an installation from source, replace /var/opt/gitlab/git-data with /home/git.

Run the command below depending on your type of installation:
Omnibus Installation

$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos
Installation from source

Before running this command you need to change the directory to where your GitLab installation is located:

$ cd /home/git/gitlab
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
Example output

Processing abcd.git
 * Created abcd (abcd.git)
Processing group/xyz.git
 * Created Group group (2)
 * Created xyz (group/xyz.git)
[...]
```